# Power-Law PDFs and Expectations

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

A random variable $X$ follows the distribution:
$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}
  Cx^2 & -1\le x\le 2,\\
  0 & \text{otherwise},
  \end{cases}$$

and $Y=X^2$. Calculate

1. $C$
2. $P(X\ge0)$
3. $E[Y]$
4. $V(Y)$

I know that I need to utilize the Power-law of PDFs but as soon as this went to integrals and derivatives I am lost and don't understand how these equations simplify.  This is my first time looking at derivatives and without explaining each step of them I'm lost immediately.

Any help would be appreciated.  Does it have to do with the equations below:
$$\int_0^1(a+1)x^adx=x^{a+1}|_0^x=1$$

1. I am at a loss for how to find the $C$ (I assume this means the $constant$.)
   But if we take the $\frac{d}{dx}x^2$ that should be $2x^{2-1}=2x$. So the $C=2$?
2. Does this follow the formula: $$P(X\ge a)=P(X\gt a)=1-F(a)$$
   If this is the case than:
   $$
   \begin{aligned} 
   F(a)&=\int_{-\infty}^af(a)du=0 \\   
   F(0)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(0^2)dx  \\
   &=1-0=1 
   \end{aligned}
   $$

So then $P(X\ge0)=1$?

3. To find the expected value for x: $$E(X)=\int xf(x)dx$$ correct?

Comment: Use $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) \ dx = 1$ to find $C$

Comment: Your approach for question 3 is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find $C$, we need to utilize this fact:

> The integral of the probability distribution function (pdf) over its domain is equal to 1.

Therefore, in mathematical notation, we have-
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = 1. $$

Now, the function $f$ that we are dealing with has non-zero output (function value) only in the interval $[-1,2]$. Therefore, we split up the integral as follows:
$$ \begin{align}1 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{-1} f(x)dx + \int_{-1}^{2} f(x)dx + \int_{2}^{\infty} f(x)dx\\ &=  \int_{-\infty}^{-1} 0\ dx + \int_{-1}^{2} Cx^2 dx + \int_{2}^{\infty} 0 \ dx \\ &=  0+ C\int_{-1}^{2} x^2 dx + 0 \textrm{, as constants are not affected by integrals}\\&= C\frac{x^3}{3}\bigg|^2_{-1} \textrm{, since the power law says:} \int x^n dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \textrm{ for } n \geq 0 \\&= C \left(\frac{2^3}{3} - \frac{(-1)^3}{3}\right) \\ &= C\left( \frac{8}{3} - \frac{-1}{3} \right)\\ &= C\left( \frac{9}{3}\right) = 3C \end{align}$$
Thus, $3C = 1$, and hence, $C = \frac{1}{3}$.

For the second question, you can use this fact-

> $ P(a \leq X \leq b) = \int_a^b f(x) dx$, for every random variable $X$ with pdf $f$.

Here, $P(X\geq 0) = P(0 \leq X \leq \infty)$. Therefore, $ P(X\geq 0) = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx.$ So then, we have -
$$ \begin{align} P(X\geq 0) &= \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx\\ &=\int_0^{2} f(x) dx + \int_2^{\infty} f(x) dx \\&= \int_0^{2} \frac{1}{3}x^2 dx + \int_2^{\infty} 0\ dx.\end{align} $$
I hope you can solve it further using the power law as we did in question 1.

Comment: How do you go from the second line to the third line?  I need that broken out as I don't understand how it goes from $C2dx$ to $C\frac{x^3}{3}$.

Comment: So then also how does this translate to the $P(X\ge0)$?

Comment: @Fototekt I added some more explanation. If you don't mind me asking, how are you studying probability without having studied calculus?

Comment: I am in a data science micro-masters course and unfortunately, this "statistics and probability" course requires calculus which I haven't taken and I'm trying to do the best I can knowing very little calculus.  With that being said i'm trying to get his class behind me and get back to the Python programming which is what i signed up for in the first place.

Comment: I've been slowly getting most of what is said but have to do a lot of research I took pre-calculus over 21 years ago...

Comment: So since $P(X\ge0)=P(0\le X\le \infty)$ would that mean it $=\infty$

Comment: I caught that too late and deleted my response.  SO then it is equal to $\frac{8}{9}$

Comment: Thank you P.J. for your help.

Comment: No problem! Good luck! :)